# Controlling file extension when inserting data into SQL Filestream column?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sqlfilestream

I have a SQL Server Express database with a 10gig limit, so I'm trying to save space by moving a big text column over to a FileStream type.

I created a new database, set up FileStreaming as well as the FileStream column and set it up as a full text index.

Then I tried inserting data into the new database from my other database (insert column to column). The resulting FileStream files are being created with no file extension (which I guess is to be expected).

I *think* this is causing my full text lookup (i.e. WHERE CONTAINS(Note,'search term')) to fail.

Is there any way that you can specify the default file extension when inserting data into a FileStream column? Or am I going to have to create a program to create temporary text files and insert them that way (I really hope not!!).

Thank you!

Comment: No, you have *no control* over what those files are going to be called, and you cannot control things like a file extension or anything, either. `FILESTREAM` is just an "opaque" container to you - you put stuff in, get it back - but there's absolutely no control over how it's stored in the mean time..

Comment: Thanks Marc, maybe I was thinking of a FileTable.  I'll have to look more into this.  My company won't pitch in to get SQL Standard, so I'm trying to find a way to move data into a file system to alleviate the strain on the 10 gig limit, but still allow a full text search.  Right now we have about 4 million records with a text field that can be up to 3000 characters.