# Best way to move data from SQL to file system (FileStream?)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sqlfilestream

At the moment I have a SQL Server Express instance with a database nearing the 10gig limit.  I have a table that stores details about activities, one column being "Note" which can be up to 3000 characters long.

I would like to take this table and convert the "Note" column to use the file system so that it frees up some database space.  I also need this column to allow full text searching.  I've poured over all the documents on FileStreams that I can find but I still can't figure out the best way to do this.

My main question is how I get my existing data (nvarchar(3000)) moved over to this new Filestream column and allow full text searches to work on this.  Everything I've read states that you have to have a column that denotes the **file extension** being used -- but I don't know how to file my data into the new field using a specific file type.  I'd be fine using .txt as the type, if I could figure out how.

Any ideas or best practices would be appreciated.  I'm not hung up on the FileStream, so I'd take any other recommendations as well.  My company is too cheap to buy SQL Standard, so I'd l

Comment: Looks very similar to [Controlling file extension when inserting data into SQL Filestream column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432735/controlling-file-extension-when-inserting-data-into-sql-filestream-column)

Comment: Bummi - yes it is an offshoot of that question.  Just looking for ideas or best practices to get this done.  I don't even know if FileStream is the way to go.  Sounds like it's not, based on the answer to the other question - unless I'm doing something wrong.